# how to download several files directly into a folder?

Tags: r

i am trying to download several files into a folder and then read them back into R

I first set my directory to the specific folder 
the first http is the main line and the urls are the files which should be download.

```
main_url <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/"
urls <- paste(main_url,c("SRR1171523/SRR1171523.sra","SRR1171524/SRR1171524.sra","SRR1171525/SRR1171525.sra","SRR1171526/SRR1171526.sra", "SRR1171527/SRR1171527.sra", "SRR1171528/SRR1171528.sra"), sep = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed like below...

## Urls

```
main_url <- 
    "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/"

urls <- 
    paste(main_url,
          c("SRR1171523/SRR1171523.sra",
            "SRR1171524/SRR1171524.sra",
            "SRR1171525/SRR1171525.sra",
            "SRR1171526/SRR1171526.sra", 
            "SRR1171527/SRR1171527.sra", 
            "SRR1171528/SRR1171528.sra"),
          sep = "")
```

## Download files

```
for(i in seq_along(urls)){

    download.file(urls[i], paste0("file_0", i, ".html"))
}
```

...and than just read downloaded files into R.

Comment: you should use this  urls <- paste(main_url,c("SRR1171523/SRR1171523.sra","SRR1171524/SRR1171524.sra","SRR1171525/SRR1171525.sra","SRR1171526/SRR1171526.sra", "SRR1171527/SRR1171527.sra", "SRR1171528/SRR1171528.sra"), sep = "")

Answer (score 0):

```
main_url <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/"
urls <- paste(main_url,c("SRR1171523/SRR1171523.sra","SRR1171524/SRR1171524.sra","SRR1171525/SRR1171525.sra","SRR1171526/SRR1171526.sra", "SRR1171527/SRR1171527.sra", "SRR1171528/SRR1171528.sra"), sep = "")

for(i in seq_along(urls)) {
  tmp <- readLines(file(urls[i],open = "r"))
  writeLines(text = tmp, con = paste0("url",1,".sra"))
}

# Reading them back
flist <- list()
for(fname in list.files()) {
  flist[[fname]] <- readLines(file(fname, open="r"))
}
```

Comment: Although as Miha said, I got `404 Not Found` errors for your urls.

Comment: I think it is because the data is big. so the best is to download them one by one instead ! because I can download them with the ugly way :-D

Comment: Oh? And the content is something else than a 404 error? Cause even in my browser it gives such an error (although a custom one)...

Comment: I see now...the urls are not properly constructed. The suffix .html is redundant.

Comment: @Dominic Comtois  I don't get any error, I can go there , just go to this link http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171523/

Comment: @Dominic Comtois look at my comment above, the last .html should be removed then you will have the direction to the files

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way to download them is as follows

```
url1 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171523/SRR1171523.sra"
url2 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171524/SRR1171524.sra"
url3 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171525/SRR1171525.sra"
url4 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171526/SRR1171526.sra
url5 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171527/SRR1171527.sra
url6 <- "http://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP038/SRP038101/SRR1171528/SRR1171528.sra


download.file(url1, "SRR1171523.sra")
download.file(url2, "SRR1171524.sra")
download.file(url3, "SRR1171525.sra")
download.file(url4, "SRR1171526.sra")
download.file(url5, "SRR1171527.sra")
download.file(url6, "SRR1171528.sra")
```